# Bootstrap Navbar misaligned when scaling back up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a simple Bootstrap navbar. Everything works fine in Chrome, but in Safari (Version 9.0.3 ) the bar can be scaled down responsively but not scaled back up. When it scales back up it stays 'stuck' vertically.

[At full-size browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwRQz.png)

[When I scale back up to full-size browser after scaling down (which does work)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZqWk.png)

This only occurs in Safari as far as I can tell.

Here is the code for the nav.

```
      <header>
    <!--Begin Nav. Nav stays inside header for margins-->
            <nav>
              <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li><a href="#bio-portrait">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#books">Books</a></li>
                <li><a href="#publications">Publications</a></li>
                <li><a href="#courses">Courses</a></li>
                <li><a href="#reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#speaking-other">Speaking</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
    <!--End Nav-->
```

Nav has no CSS properties apart from Bootstrap other than borders on top and bottom. Here's relevant lines:

```
header, body {
  margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 100%;
}

nav {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

I have tried nesting the nav in a .container-fluid but that also didn't help.

Comment: At least as far as your posted code goes, you haven't closed the `ul` tag.

Comment: Thank you, I did catch that after I made the post! Unfortunately the initial problem does remain.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Unfortunately, there is not enough information here to help you. At minimum, you need to post some of your CSS as well. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question. Great questions get faster, better responses

Comment: Thank you, Ochi. I have pasted relevant CSS.

Comment: Turns out this is a common bug: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/